# How can I efficiently create the prefix failure array of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create the failure array of a string about 100000 letters long, but my code seems to take forever to run.

```
x = input("::").replace("\n","").strip()
p = ""
for count in range(len(x)-1):
    count+=1
    myn = 0
    for c in range(count):
        c+=1
        if x[c:count] == x[:len(x[c:count])] and myn < len(x[c:count]):
            myn = len(x[c:count])
            break
    p += str(myn)+" "
print(p+"0")
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Edit: I believe something called the KMP algorithm would do this. Can anyone show me how I would do this?

Comment: In words, what should the result string look like?

Comment: So at each character it finds the longest substring ending at that character that is also a prefix of the whole string, not including the obvious full string from beginning to character. Each is followed by a space.